# Could sudo effective uid is not 0 still use reboot command?

Tags: linux, mount, sudo, reboot

I have a remote server, I am trying to recover some deleted files. I search and called `unmount` according to one tutorial, I think it's after `unmount -l /dev/sda1` somehow it suddenly ran into

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

Some says reboot would solve this, but when I `reboot` it says `Need to be root`.

Is there any solution? Or the only way to reboot is to manually press the button?

Comment: Your system is broken. Can you boot from a LiveUSB?

Comment: after manually reboot it is recovered.. manually operating is so inconvenient..